# Quando devo salvar dados da minha aplicação no registro do sistema?

Tags: java

Preciso armazenar algumas informações da minha aplicação para quando o usuário iniciá-la novamente ser carregado os dados da ultima utilização. A principio pensei em utilizar o registro do Windows (nesse caso tenho certeza que a aplicação só rodará em ambiente Win), procurei então por como fazer e encontrei a classe `Preferences`.

Eu tenho um HashMap com aproximadamente 10 valores (pode ser que com o tempo apareçam outras) que representam as preferências do usuário. O problema é que `Preferences` não permite armazenar um `Map`, então eu teria que percorrê-lo inserindo cada String às preferências:

```
// Map de preferências
Map<String,String> prefsMap = new HashMap<>();
prefsMap.put("last_report", "10/10/1950");
prefsMap.put("last_dir", "C:\\Users\\UserName\\");
prefsMap.put("splash", "false");
prefsMap.put("load_style", "true");
// outros 6 valores...

// Inserindo no Registro
Preferences prefs = Preferences.systemNodeForPackage(Main.class);
for(Map.Entry<String,String> each : prefsMap.entrySet())
   prefs.put(each.getKey(), each.getValue());
```

Olhando esse código, parece que vai ficar uma coisa "feia" no registro pela quantidade de keys. No `Map`, para mim é normal mas não sei como isso ficará no *reg* do sistema por nunca ter trabalhado com isso anteriormente. E ai vem minhas dúvidas:

1. Devo usar o registro do S.O. para armazenar informações desse tipo? Por "desse tipo", considere informações básicas de uma aplicação. Se a resposta for não, quando então devo fazer uso do registro do sistema?
2. Como dito antes, pode ser que apareçam novas preferências com o
   tempo. É melhor abandonar a ideia de salvar no registro e criar um
   arquivo (.txt) com as preferências?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usar o registro do Windows é mais complicado do que usar arquivo texto ou banco de dados embarcado.

Respostas:

> 1. Devo usar o registro do S.O. para armazenar informações desse tipo? Por "desse tipo", considere informações básicas de uma aplicação.

Não, porque:

- O registro do Windows não é intuitivo para o usuário configurar tanto quanto um arquivo texto.
- Há ambientes onde o usuário não tem permissão de usar o editor de registro do Windows, e há ainda ambientes onde os aplicativos não têm permissão de escrever no registro, nem mesmo na área do usuário.
- Teu sistema provavelmente já usa banco de dados então você já está muito melhor munido para utilizar este recurso. O Java também oferece mecanismos satisfatórios para escrever em arquivos de propriedades ou em arquivos textos customizados (serialização de objetos para texto, JSon...)

> Se a resposta for não, quando então devo fazer uso do registro do
> sistema?

Talvez para prover uma configuração muito pouco utilizada e que você faça questão de manter obscura para que não atraia alterações experimentais do usuário.

#### Salvando definições do aplicativo em arquivo texto

O Windows oferece uma pasta específica para dados de aplicativo, que é a **AppData**. Ela fica sob a pasta do usuário e o usuário sempre tem permissão de escrever ali (diferente da pasta *Program Files*, por exemplo).

Para obter esta pasta:

```
// retorna algo como "C:\Users\caffé\AppData\Roaming"
String pastaDadosDoAplicativo = System.getenv("APPDATA");
```

Nela você pode criar uma subpasta para o seu próprio aplicativo.

Outro ponto positivo de escrever ali as definições do aplicativo é que elas não ficam evidente ao usuário, de modo que não o convidam a alterá-las ou a perder tempo preocupando-se com elas.

<sub>Em tempo: "usuário ter permissão de escrever" é o mesmo que o "aplicativo ter permissão de escrever" no caso de o aplicativo ser executado sob as credenciais do usuário.</sub>

Comment: Caffé, eu não utilizo banco de dados porque é uma aplicação *desktop* que não armazena informações. Mas eu, eu, estou pretendendo guardar alguns dados para quando o usuário executá-la novamente não estar com a cara de "primeira vez". Para ficar mais claro: São dados de personalização apenas, por isso não vejo muita vantagem em usar um BD embarcado para armazenar de 10~12 `strings`. **ps:** Não entendi a parte de ser intuitivo para o usuário, está supondo que o usuário terá acesso e poderá editar essas informações? Esses dados são importantes só para modificar a aparência da aplicação.

Comment: @rrnan Seria interessante ser intuitivo se o usuário precisasse alterar. Quanto ao usuário **ter acesso** a alterar, não está no seu controle nem salvando em arquivo texto nem salvando no registro do Windows - ambos, por padrão, o usuário pode alterar; a não ser que você criptografe. Sugestão: vá de arquivo texto :-)

Comment: @rrnan Adicionei uma sugestão de onde guardar o arquivo texto.

Comment: Cara, curti muito essa de salvar em %AppData%. Seu comentário anterior também me deu uma luz, talvez eu crie algo criptografado para o usuário não fuçar e um arquivo para ele modificar caso ache necessário. Vou fazer alguns testes...

Comment: Acabei fazendo dessa forma, notei que eu estava querendo complicar demais, hehe. Agradeço a ajuda.

Answer (score 1):

Você poderia pensar seguintes soluções:

- Utlizar um banco de dados embarcado com o [HSQLDB](http://hsqldb.org/) e o [H2](http://www.h2database.com/html/main.html).
- Caso realmente haja poucas informações, guarde em um arquivo texto no formato de `.properties`.

Acredito que essas alternativas lhe darão uma solução mais fácil de implementar, por não há necessidade de se manuzear registros do sistema. Além disso, sua solução independe do Sistema Operacional, que sempre é uma boa caracteristica da mesma.

Comment: Mas como eu disse: A plataforma será Windows e isso está garantido. Minhas dúvidas estão no ponto 1 e 2 da pergunta.

Comment: A despeito da multiplataforma, condorco com o uso de banco de dados e arquivos texto. +1

Comment: Não vejo problemas essa quantidade de dados no registro do windows, desde que isso seja transparente para o usuário (ele não tenha que gerenciar esses registros). Acredito qpenas que hajam soluções mais simples e robustas como demostradas na resposta. O problema de se utilizar registros do windows é que, volta e meia, eles criam problemas inesperados.

Comment: @EduardoFernandes obrigado, ajudou bastante. Procurei e encontrei algumas desvantagens depois de ler o seu comentário.

Comment: Caro @rrnan, caso a resposta seja a correta para sua pergunta, por favor a marque clicando no sinal de "check". Obrigado.